# Please breakdown this MySQL statement for me

Tags: mysql, sql

I came up with this solution in my class by piecing together Internet knowledge. Please break this down for me I would love to know how I made it work. Specifically the t.s and the closing t.

```
SELECT 
CourseType, 
GPA, 
NumberOfStudents * 100 / t.s AS `Percentage of Students`
FROM View1 
CROSS JOIN 
( 
SELECT 
SUM(NumberOfStudents) AS s 
FROM View1) t;
```

Comment: Do you know what a [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) is? Or a table alias?

Comment: I am familiar with subqueries, I typically close them off as )sub. Not sure about table alias

Comment: Well, in that case your alias is `sub`.

Comment: Ahhh, I get it now. Thank You. Class is a requirement and I'm an electrical engineer. Silly curriculum

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses a subquery. A sub-query is a query that is done within another query. In your case, your subquery is:

```
( 
SELECT 
SUM(NumberOfStudents) AS s 
FROM View1)
```

When you create subqueries, you need to give them an alias. An alias is just a name you give a subquery, so you can use it in the main query.
In your example, you named your subquery "t".

Fields can also have aliases. in your subquery, you created a field `SUM(NumberOfStudents)`, and you named it s.

Going back to your question, you use the aliases to address fields inside the subquery. in your case, when you do `100 / t.s` you are basically saying:

"I want to divide 100 by the field s from my subquery t".

The other concept that is important in your query is the Cross join. A cross join is the Cartesian product of two tables.

You can find a great and intuitive explanation of how a cross join works in the following link:

[https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-cross-join-with-examples/#:~:text=The%20CROSS%20JOIN%20is%20used,also%20known%20as%20cartesian%20join.&text=The%20main%20idea%20of%20the,product%20of%20the%20joined%20tables](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-cross-join-with-examples/#:%7E:text=The%20CROSS%20JOIN%20is%20used,also%20known%20as%20cartesian%20join.&text=The%20main%20idea%20of%20the,product%20of%20the%20joined%20tables).

I this case, the use is simpler than that. your subquery should return only one value, which is the sum of all students. And since a cross join basically pairs every row of one table with every row from the other, your cross join just provides a way to use the number of students as a constant value for the calculation of the percentage of students in the main query.

Comment: Wonderful explanation. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this uses window functions:

```
SELECT v.CourseType, v.GPA, 
       v.NumberOfStudents * 100 / SUM(v.NumberOfStudents) OVER () AS Percentage_of_Students
FROM View1 v;
```

If you are learning SQL, you might as well learn the correct way to express logic.

Notes:

- Use meaningful table aliases (abbreviations for the table/view names).
- Qualify column references.  This is less important in a query with only one table reference, but it is a good habit.
- Window functions allow you to summarize data across multiple rows, without using an explicit `JOIN`.